# Как сделать 2 асинхронных запроса и отследить окончание каждого

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как сделать 2 асинхронных запроса и отследить окончание каждого ?

К примеру есть 2 запроса:

```
User.find({}, (err, users) => {
  users = users;
});

Category.find({}, (err, categories) => {
  categories = categories;
});

res.json({ users, categories });
```

И когда прийдёт ответ от 2х запросов, чтобы не терять производительность, вернуть ответ от сервера ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую прочитать про [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) и использовать `Promise.all`.

Если кратко: данный метод принимает массив промисов и будет выполнен когда будут выполнены все "обещания" (промисы)

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, "foo"] через 0.1сек
});
```

Для Вашего случая `p1` и `p2` должны возвращать промисы, которые будет загружать данные (достаточно ваши методы обернуть в промисы, а в коллбэках вызывать `resolve()`).

Альтернативный вариант:

```
const users = null;
const categories = null

const sendData = () => {
  if (users && categories) {
    res.json({ users, categories });
    // next();
  }
};

User.find({}, (err, u) => { users = u; sendData(); });
Category.find({}, (err, c) => { categories = c; sendData(); });
```

Ещё один вариант, использовать цепочку коллбэков, но тогда теряется производительность, хотя это самый простой вариант, который практически всегда использовали до появления ES6.